# Leaflet maps: How to stop all the popups from closing when one is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, gis

Ok, so I have a huge mapping project using leaflet and I've got the following overrides:

```js
//set defaults for popups
L.Popup.options = {
    autoClose: false,
    closeButon: false
     };
```

According to the documentation, this should prevent the popups from closing when I open one. Why are all the popups still closing when I click the map?

Comment: Actually, where is the close all popups code called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure how you tested this, but if you created a single instance of a Popup and then added the same one on your map then it only changed the position of it, not creating a new one on the map. You will need to create 3 different popups for 3 different markers in order to keep them opened.

Here is the example of the code that does what you want (leaflet version 1.0.0-rc3):

```
var map = new L.Map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var newpopup = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false,
  autoClose: false
}).setContent("popup 1");
var newpopup2 = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false,
  autoClose: false
}).setContent("popup2");
var newpopup3 = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false,
  autoClose: false
}).setContent("popup3");

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.49, -0.09]).addTo(map).bindPopup(newpopup);

L.marker([51.51, -0.091]).addTo(map).bindPopup(newpopup2);

L.marker([51.51, -0.12]).addTo(map).bindPopup(newpopup3);
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mallack/yVLJf/170/) that demonstrates this:

[image]

Comment: Then click one.. they all close when it reopens.

Comment: I don't understand, this isn't the answer you wanted? With this solution a popup can be closed only if you click on the X or on the marker again. They will all stay opened as you click and open other ones.

Comment: maybe the OP meant this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66637350/1243247